# Unable to change text color using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am unable to change the text color using jQuery.I have gone through other similar questions and tried to implement the solutions but somehow its not working. Not sure where I am going wrong. please help. I have created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8cv1zqp3/)

**CODE**
**HTML**

```
    <div class="wrapper">
<button class="addItem">Add Item</button>
<button class="removeItem">Remove Last Item</button>
<div class="clear">

</div>
<div class="colr blue">blue</div>
<div class="colr red">red</div>
<div class="clear">

</div>
<ul class="items">
<li class="newItem">ONE</li>
<li class="newItem">ONE</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
.colr{
  height:20px;
  width:50px;
  float:left;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.blue{
  background:blue;

}

.red{
  background:red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addItem').click(function(){
    $('.items').append("<li class=\'newItem\'>NEW ITEM</li>");
  });
  $('.removeItem').click(function(){
    $('.items li:last-child').remove();

  });
  $('blue').click(function(){
    $('.items').css('color','blue');
  });
  $('red').click(function(){
    $('.newItem').css('color','red');
  });
});
```

Comment: Your selectors are wrong; `'blue'` should be `'.blue'`, `'red'` should be `'.red'`

Comment: ah silly me thanks :)

Comment: you can use `console.log` to see where is a fault. Firstly, add it to handler. If console does not show anything, then check the `$('blue').length` if it is equal to `0`, then your selector is wrong.

Comment: @FreeLightman i will keep that in mind :) I am beginner using jQuery from few days sometime i make silliest of mistakes like i did today

Comment: @Shalini that's why I advice you to check yourself because you will have a lot of errors when write any script first time.

Comment: @FreeLightman yes I should splly since i am a beginner i tend to make lot of mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this code

```
$('.blue').click(function(){ 
    $('.items').css('color','blue');
  });
  $('.red').click(function(){
    $('.newItem').css('color','red');
  });
```

Js fiddle link [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/hc2hqhd5/)